# Codeigniter URL Rewrite SSL HTTPS

Tags: codeigniter, mod-rewrite, ssl, https, url-rewriting

Inside the LAN, we are good to go… folks access our intranet using http:// intranet All links and URLs work just fine and dandy (I removed index.php from links using URL Rewriting).

We are required to give access to the Intranet to certain outside folks.. we are accomplishing this using FTMG, the same way in which Outlook Web Access works.

Now, calls to https:// intranet.domain.org work, but links within the site do not work… for example:

- https:// intranet.domain.org works
- https:// intranet works
- https:// intranet.domain.org/homepage **FAILS**
- https:// intranet.domain.org/index.php/homepage works
- https:// intranet/index.php/homepage works

***(Disregard space after https://, I received errors for invalid links)***

Taking away the 's' from https, and the entire site functions properly.

The dilemma should be clear… implementing the URL Rewriting is not work with https…

How do I make it work?

Note:
my config file =

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
```

my .htaccess file =

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this will be of some help [HTTP/HTTPS, without index.php, using htaccess](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/86113/)

Comment: First thing I came across... tried every scenario, every combination of code that could be tried and nothing. Nothing works! Makes no sense... only one sincere post on the topic... not a single answer across the 4 forums I've posted this too... its as if i am the only one with the problem and no one else has ever heard of it, lol. Frustrating!

Comment: @westexasman It is very odd, I don't see why it wouldn't be working, I'm sure it will be something simple, as it always is in cases like this. Sorry I'm not able to help you. Good luck, hang in there.

Comment: It ended up working after all... it doesn't work inside our network, but it does work outside our network, so possibly a routing issue inside. Either way, not going to mess with it anymore!